# Utilizando ancoras de navegação "target" e o histórico no navegador ficando lotado!

Tags: html5, css3

Estou utilizando Ancoras em uma aplicação de slides em suas devidas setas de recuar e avançar, mas a cada clique nas setas ancoradas com links das próprias posições e imagens definidas no meu diretório, vai armazenando um conteúdo no histórico do browser, e acaba ficando lotado cheio de paginas em branco, que no caso é a minha própria pagina Html que tem o slide, teria algum modo de impedir esse armazenamento absurdo ??  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dorwO.png

Comment: Cara suas setas são links? Tipo `<a href="#">`  ? Já tentou com `event.preventDefault()` ?

Comment: Sim, elas são <a href="#">  que consequentemente o histórico fica cheio

Comment: Tentei usar esse comando aí que você mencionou, porém não sei direito como procedi